# Linear vector search too slow for online judge

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Problem Statement: We have to input a vector and then there is a certain number of queries. For one particular query, we have to search for that number in the vector. If found we print."Yes " and if not found we print the next greater number to the query and print "No ".
The vector is sorted.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
    int size,q,nq=0;
    cin>>size;
    vector<int> vec1;
    int element;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cin>>element;
        vec1.push_back(element);
    }
    cin>>q;
    for(int j=0;j<q;j++)
    {
        cin>>nq;
        for(int k=0;k<vec1.size();k++)
        {
            if(vec1[k]==nq)
            {
                cout<<"Yes "<<k+1<<endl;
                break;
            }
            else if(vec1[k]>nq)
            {
                cout<<"No "<<k+1<<endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }     
    return 0;
}
```

The code runs perfectly but for some test cases, there is an error due to time.
I need to improve this code. I am struggling with this as I have just learned about std::vector.

Comment: If the vector is sorted, a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) is O(log(n)) while your linear search in O(n). It should greatly speep up the research.

Comment: When solving programming contest-type questions, always look at the size limits that are part of the problem statement. The simple and naive approach is rarely fast enough, but often a good baseline for comparing to a wildly different implementation.

Comment: Regardless of time constraint (where you should use binary_search as mentioned), your code doesn't seem to do what is requested. If you found the number, you print "Yes" and the next number in the vector, but if I understood correctly, you should only print the next number in case of "No".

Answer (score 0):

as this problem related to sorted vector it requires use Binary Search.
Binary search allows to answer queries with *O(Log(N))* vs *O(N)* complexity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity). So this is why your implementation is too slow for this problem.

Here is manual implementation [Using Binary Search with Vectors.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774858/using-binary-search-with-vectors)
And also it is more clear to use [std::lower_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) function. It does exact the thing needed:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

    int main() {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
        int size,q,nq=0;
        cin>>size;
        vector<int> vec1;
        int element;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            cin>>element;
            vec1.push_back(element);
        }
        cin>>q;
    
        vector<int>::iterator qit;
    
        for(int j=0;j<q;j++)
        {
            cin>>nq;
    
            qit = std::lower_bound(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), nq);
    
            if(qit != vec1.end())
            {
                if(*qit == nq)
                    cout << "Yes " << (qit - vec1.begin());
                else cout << "No " << *qit << " " << (qit - vec1.begin());
            }
            else cout << "No " << (qit - vec1.begin());
        }     
        return 0;
    }
```